# Регулярное выражение для преобразовании текстовой ссылки в нормальную

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
#(^|\s|\()((http(s?)://)|(www\.))(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i
```

> google.ru - **не поддерживается**
>
> www.google.ru - поддерживается

Что исправить в регулярке, чтобы поддерживался первый вариант?

Comment: что значит нормальная, и что значит текстовая ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#(^|\s|\()((http(s?)://)|(www\.)?)(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i
```

должно взлететь